# Why $\{\alpha_n\},\{\beta_n\}$ with this property exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{\alpha_n\},\{\beta_n\}$ be real valued sequences, such that $\alpha_n<\beta_n$, $\alpha_{n-1}<\beta_n$ and $\beta_1>0$, such that $\alpha_n\to\alpha$, $\beta_n\to \beta$ where $\alpha\le\beta$.

How to be sure that such $\{\alpha_n\},\{\beta_n\}$ exist for each $-\infty\le\alpha\le\beta\le+\infty$?

Comment: The way you've written is right now, it's trivial. If $\alpha < \beta$ just let $\alpha_n := \alpha$ and $\beta_n := \beta$ for all $n$. Otherwise let $\beta_n$ be constant and pick any strictly increasing sequence converging to $\alpha$ for the $\alpha_n$s. Pretty sure you meant to write something else.

Comment: @StefanMesken, but that does not take care of $\beta_1>0$

Comment: May I ask: How did this question come up? It feels like a really unnatural question to me. (Maybe something a programmer might run into?)

Comment: These sequences are mentioned in Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, theorem 3.54's proof, where he proves that if a series converges conditionally, then every real is a limit for some rearrangement. If you ask, I will add pictures in that reference. @StefanMesken

Comment: Thanks, I don't need a picture of this. I was just curious to get an idea why someone might be interested in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My earlier comments ended up a bit messier than I would like. Hence I decided to write up an answer and be a bit more careful about the details:

I assume that $- \infty < \alpha \le \beta < \infty$ and leave the remaining cases up to you. (They are simpler but rather annoying, since there are several cases to consider.)

For each $n$ let
$$
\alpha_n = \alpha - \frac{1}{n}
$$
and
$$
\beta_n = \beta + \frac{2 | \beta | +1 }{n}.
$$
This guarantees $\alpha_n \to_{n \to \infty} \alpha$ and $\beta_n \to_{n \to \infty} \beta$.

Moreover, since $\alpha \le \beta$ and $\alpha_n < \alpha \le \beta < \beta_m$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$ we have that $\alpha_n, \alpha_{n-1} < \beta_n$.

Finally $\beta_1 = \beta + 2 | \beta | + 1 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your effort.

Comment: You're welcome!